# Laravel JWT Authentication without User Model

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, dingo-api

I'm trying to build a laravel application and API for mobile users in the same project. The main web is actually a backend of a website and require proper authentication that I have already implemented. And the api also need to authenticate but with different credentials (not user model from web).

At this point I have added dingo api in my project and its working fine. But now I also need to add jwt for dingo. Problem is jwt works with App\User Model by default and I don't want to authenticate api users with web user credentials. Please suggest me what is the best way to work this out. Thanks

Comment: In case someone comes here to search for the answer, I have written an article for this topic: https://medium.com/@sirajul.anik/passwordless-otp-based-login-returning-jwt-with-tymon-jwt-auth-d463287cb6ca

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the docs its looks like you specify the auth provider in the config.php file that get published with `php artisan vendor:publish`

Set the `auth` to your provider:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/develop/config/config.php#L252

Or you can specify which driver and/or user provider you are using in the `app.php` config file:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L69
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L70

Update:

1. Make migration to hold clients table: `php artisan make:migration
   create_clients_table`
2. Update the migration file as desired.
3. Create the Clients model with `php artisan make:model Client`
4. Update the model to match the migration and add any relationships.
5. Run the migration.

That should make it so [this](https://prnt.sc/ht7cjv) will work

You may need to update accordingly to something like:

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'clients',
],
```

or possibly:

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'jwt',
],
```

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L46

Comment: Yes I have already tried that auth.php configuration. I'm new to laravel. Do I have to create another provider for this? in my auth.php I have enabled 2nd array for api guard. And `
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'clients' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Client::class,
         ],
    ],`

Comment: What is the "proper authentication" you implemented?

Comment: Yes I have already tried that auth.php configuration. I'm new to laravel. Do I have to create another provider for this? in my auth.php I have enabled 2nd array for api guard.   [link] http://prntscr.com/ht7cjv [/link] and then api routes in my routes/api.php so technically it should use client model right?

Comment: laravel builtin auth

Comment: adding another key will not help in this situation unless you are referencing  off that key

Comment: Do I have to create my own provider?

Comment: If you are using default built in authentication, then there is a default `User.php.` model. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php

Comment: Yes but I don't want to use User.php model for my api requests. I want to create another Model. Lets call it Client. That simply has key and secret which generates token. No password or anything. Api users are different in my case.

Comment: So do you want the JWT token to be completely separate from users, then you would need to create a new model and migration to hold that.

Comment: I have already created that model and its migrations. but the problem is when I try to generate token, it is still going to User Model. I have even defined authentication routes in routes/api.php so so these requests should use api guard that is App/Client right?

Comment: @AhsanShabbir I had the same problem and created an own authentication provider and referenced in `config/jwt.php`. In this provider you can implement the lookup method yourself.